# how to remove input fields according to values given in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a select box which looks like 
[image: Picture of selected box]

My html code looks like this,

```
<div class="box-body" >
<span class="successMessage" th:text="${dataSuccess}" style="color: green; align-self:flex-end"></span>
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Person Id</th>
                       <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Age</th>
                      <th>Sex</th>
                      <th>District</th>
                      <th>VDC/MUNICIPAL</th>
                      <th>Ward No.</th>
                      <th>Xray Status</th>
                      <th>Remarks</th>
                     <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
                        </thead>
        <tbody  th:each="persons : ${part}">
        <form  method="post" th:action="@{/xraystatus(id=${persons.id})}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
         <td th:text="${persons.id}" id="xrayid"></td>
         <td th:text="${persons.name}"></td>
         <td th:text="${persons.lastName}"></td >
         <td th:text="${persons.age}"></td>
         <td th:text="${persons.sex}"> </td>
         <td th:text="${persons.district}"></td>
         <td th:text="${persons.district}"></td>
         <td th:text="${persons.wardNo}"></td>
          <td>


   <div class="checkbox"  >
     <select name="xraystatus" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" style="width:61px"  >                            
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="1">Yes</option>
         <option value="0">No</option>
         <option value="2">Possible</option>
         <option value="3">Exempted</option>
          </select>
          </div>


        </td>
        <td >
        <input type="text" name="remarks"  >
        <!--</div>-->
        </td>
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button> </td>
        </form>
        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

My problem here is on checkbox only. for e.g if value 1 is returned from back-end, means yes is selected and other three thymeleaf options are ignored. So only yes is selected and shown in choose option box. But when "yes" is selected i want to show other three options too. I tried to add manual options but this idea seems to have the same option duplicated. how can this be solved?

Comment: What you have explained is contradicting to me, 

Case 01: if value 1 is returned from back-end, means yes is selected and other three thymeleaf options are ignored.
Case 02: But when "yes" is selected i want to show other three options too.

You can hide other option by adding a th:if="${your condition here}". But I cannot understand case 02

Comment: my checkbox should contain 4 values. yes,no,possible and Exempted. but by default one should be selected(according to value sent from back end).

Comment: Add th:value="*{value from model}" to your select component, <select name="xraystatus" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" style="width:61px"  th:value="*{value from model}">